# Android detect if constructor called in design mode?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, constructor

It is probably well know that eclipse calls a component's constructor when it has to show the component in the XML graphical layout, so it knows how it will look like.

How do I check in a constructor call if the call was made for design time (above case) or for actual runtime?

Answer (score 13):

I think you're looking for [`View.isInEditMode()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isInEditMode())

Comment: @cdbeelala89  This answer should be the "Accepted Answer"http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow